# Background for notification icons

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar, android-icons

I am trying to figure out why different icons in the notification area have different backgrounds.

Please see attached screenshot. 'USB debugging conencted' has a solid color background, but other two notification icons don't have the same greenish background. In my app, notifications generated from two different places similarly have different backgrounds. And.. the icons used are similar - there's no solid vs transparent difference in them, the code is standard and simple - `setSmallIcon()`. As such, there's no indication why system would treat the icons differently.

This is a very fine detail, and I haven't been able to find any answers anywhere else. I have finally turned to the experts here. Does anyone have any idea?

[image: notifications-screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

This is based on Notification priority. Notifications with PRIORITY_MIN have the 'dark' background like 'Time to Work' notification in the screenshot. Those with PRIORITY_HIGH (and I think PRIORITY_MAX too) have the greenish background.